Hard time with line spacing
I have a long LaTeX document from which I want to extract just a very small piece.
I have thus copy pasted the code of the long document into a standalone document. The code is exactly the same (at least for the extracted piece), but when I generate both documents I have different interline spacing. Yet, I would absolutely need to have the same spacing.
All the spacing elements of LaTeX I am aware of (parindent, parskip, rightskip, leftskip, baselineskip, lineskip and parfillskip) have the same value. I am quite puzzled. My guess is that another element exists and governs the interline spacing that I don't know.
Of course I cannot really provide any reduced example as the result would look exactly as the extracted piece but not as the original one.
I thus attached three pictures of the results:

The original long document

The extraction

Both put side by side so that the difference is clearly visible


I have spent quite a bunch of time trying to change these parameters I know, and nothing gives the same results (the only thing that I got as close as possible was to set baselineskip to 11.98996pt in the extraction while in the original document it's 9.89993pt - I guess that's the solution I will keep if I have no other choice, but I really don't understand what's going on here.
If anyone has any idea, I am sincerely grateful, I'm getting quite crazy with this...
EDIT: Here is a minimal code of what I extracted:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=12.86cm,paperwidth=18.2cm, left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}
\sloppy
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor  = blue, citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\setstretch{0.9}
\TPMargin{0.00001mm}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{13.04991pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}

\definecolor{LightOrange}{cmyk}{0,0.04,0.07,0.04}%
\definecolor{DarkGreen}{cmyk}{0.7,0,1,0.4}%
\colorlet{BackgroundColour}{LightOrange}
\colorlet{SubtitlesTextColour}{DarkGreen}%
\colorlet{TextColour}{black}%

\newfontfamily\MyFont{Helvetica Neue Light} 
\newcommand{\SubtitlesFontSize}{\fontsize{12}{14}}
\newcommand{\NamesFontSize}{\fontsize{10}{11}}
\newcommand{\TextFontSize}{\fontsize{9}{11}}
\newcommand{\SubtitlesStyle}{\MyFont\SubtitlesFontSize\color{SubtitlesTextColour}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\NamesStyle}{\MyFont\NamesFontSize\color{SubtitlesTextColour}\bfseries}
\newcommand{\TextStyle}{\MyFont\TextFontSize\color{TextColour}\mdseries}


\begin{textblock*}{18cm}[0.5,0](9.1cm,0.1cm)

    \textblockcolour{BackgroundColour}
    \hrule
    \begin{center}
    \setstretch{0.9}
    \begin{minipage}[c][][c]{17cm}
        \setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
        {\SubtitlesStyle\noindent Main Title}
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \noindent{\NamesStyle{Subtitle One}}\vspace{0mm}\\
            \noindent{\TextStyle Test to show that line spacing here is much larger, but parindent (\the\parindent), parskip (\the\parskip), rightskip (\the\rightskip), leftskip (\the\leftskip), baselineskip (\the\baselineskip), lineskip (\the\lineskip), and parfillskip (\the\parfillskip) are exactly identical across the two texts.}\vspace{2mm}\\
            \noindent{\NamesStyle{Subtitle Two}}\vspace{0mm}\\
            \noindent{\TextStyle Test to show that line spacing here is much larger, but parindent (\the\parindent), parskip (\the\parskip), rightskip (\the\rightskip), leftskip (\the\leftskip), baselineskip (\the\baselineskip), lineskip (\the\lineskip), and parfillskip (\the\parfillskip) are exactly identical across the two texts.}\vspace{1mm}\columnbreak\\
            \noindent{\NamesStyle{Subtitle Three}}\vspace{0mm}\vspace{0mm}\\
            \noindent{\TextStyle Test to show that line spacing here is much larger, but parindent (\the\parindent), parskip (\the\parskip), rightskip (\the\rightskip), leftskip (\the\leftskip), baselineskip (\the\baselineskip), lineskip (\the\lineskip), and parfillskip (\the\parfillskip) are exactly identical across the two texts.}\vspace{2mm}\\
            \noindent{\NamesStyle{Subtitle Four}}\vspace{0mm}\\
            \noindent{\TextStyle Test to show that line spacing here is much larger, but parindent (\the\parindent), parskip (\the\parskip), rightskip (\the\rightskip), leftskip (\the\leftskip), baselineskip (\the\baselineskip), lineskip (\the\lineskip), and parfillskip (\the\parfillskip) are exactly identical across the two texts.}\\
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2mm}
    \hrule
\end{textblock*}



\end{document}


You have provided no code, so how should we know what exactly you are doing.

https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

most likely one of the code sections you have not shown is missing a \par or blank, line but debugging code with no information about the code is not easy.

baselineskip of 9.9pt looks rather odd, what is your font size? (but don't answer that:  provide a small sample document that would answer all such questions)

Could you post the code you used to make the extraction?  Is there a large box at the top of the next page in the original document?

My apologies for that, I did not realize that a minimal code would be needed. I tried to create one, based on what I extracted:

Thanks for the example., as predicted you have \TextFontSize inside a group that ends before the paragraph ends. (you really should remove all those \noindent  and \vspace which further obfuscate the code)

\setstretch{0.9}  can't really have a good outcome.

\noindent does not take a formal argument. Hence, noindent{xyz} is the same as \noindent xyz.

You have given no information but I would guess you have something equivalent to

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%parbox just to show side by side
\parbox[t]{5cm}{

{\baselineskip=9.5pt
test test test test test test [\the\baselineskip]
test test test test test test
test test test test test test
test test test test test test
}

}
%
\parbox[t]{5cm}{

{\baselineskip=9.5pt
test test test test test test [\the\baselineskip]
test test test test test test
test test test test test test
test test test test test test

}

}


\end{document}

Where in the first case the group ends before the end of paragraph and so the \baselineskip setting is restored and the usual (12pt) setting is used, even though the value within the paragraph as shown by \the\baselineskip is 9.5pt.
In the second case the paragraph ends before the end of group and so it is set with the current (inappropriately small) setting of 9.5pt

Thank you David for your reply, it definitely sounds promising - I will look into it!
